# traefik pathprefixstrip with kubernetes ingress and redirect doesn't work

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, kubernetes-ingress

I use traefik with Kubernetes Ingress with following configuration:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.frontend.rule.type: PathPrefixStrip
  name: loxberry
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: hostname
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /loxberry
        backend:
          serviceName: loxberry-service
          servicePort: 80
```

when I try to open my service with `hostname/loxberry` it gets redirected to 
`hostname/admin/system/index.cgi`

curl to `hostname/loxberry` gives me following result:

```
<title>LoxBerry</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/admin/system/index.cgi" />
```

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Can you share your target service `loxberry-service`?

Comment: `kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: loxberry-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: loxberry
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    name: web
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 21
    targetPort: 21
    name: ssh
  - protocol: UDP
    port: 137
    targetPort: 137
    name: port1
  - protocol: UDP
    port: 138
    targetPort: 138
    name: port2
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 139
    targetPort: 139
    name: port3
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 445
    targetPort: 445
    name: ssl`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using [Meta refresh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) method here for automatic redirection:

> meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/admin/system/index.cgi"

`http-equiv="refresh"` method for refreshing current web page with `URL` parameter

`content` parameter specifies the time interval in seconds, here you have set `0` immediate action;

Therefore, you get redirection of `hostname/loxberry` to the target `hostname/admin/system/index.cgi`.